# Is there any alternative SDK for Java to access AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

My applications need access to DynamoDB, and are deployed to AWS Lambda. I've tried `com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-dynamodb` and `software.amazon.awssdk.dynamodb` to implement the codes of accessing DynamoDB. However, both of them need several seconds to initialize when the Lambda is triggered with cold start. In the same time, for applications implemented with Python and `boto3`, they need only less than 1 second to initialize before the application can start accessing DynamoDB.

PS. Lambda is configured with 3GB RAM to minimize the execution time.

Is there any other alternative library that is more lightweight than the official SDK for DynamoDB? Or how can I configure the SDK to speed it up for shorter cold start in Lambda?

Comment: We migrated to NodeJS for this reason. Sorry.